# Pick random integers from list elements of same index and generate a list

Tags: python, list, random

I have two lists `a` & `b` and I need to pick a random element of `a[i]` and `b[i]` and generate `z`.

```
a = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
b = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

z = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I used the below mentioned code:

```
import random
z = []
for i in range(6):
    value = random(a[i],b[i])
    z.append(value)
print z
```

and I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.choice` (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)).

> Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

It selects one value from a list of values. For each iteration, you can just create a list of `a[i]` and `b[i]`.

```
for i in range(6):
    value = random.choice([a[i],b[i]])
    z.append(value)
print( z)

# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Another option is to use `random.sample` where `k=1` here and `[a[i],b[i]]` is the population as following

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set

```
value = random.sample([a[i],b[i]], 1)
z.append(value[0])
```

Here `value[0]` is used because `value` is a list containing single element so by using `[0]` you get that element without the list.

Answer (score 0):

First off all you have to import random module.

```
import random
```

Then you can call any of its method:

```
random.random()
```

Furthermore you have should choose `random.choice()`:

```
value = random.sample([a[i],b[i]], 1)
```

Comment: Two things: The OP already imported random. Secondly, `random.random` returns a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: My first intent was answer what caused your error msg.
The other parts was answered @Bazingaa already. Have a good work!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `random` as if it's a function, when in fact it's a module.  You need to use `random.choice` to choose one of the two options:

```
value = random.choice([a[i],b[i]])
```